# Are relative uncertainties additive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, percentages

I'm given a quantity which is defined as $$a=\frac{bcd}{ef}$$
and I know the relative uncertainties in each of $b,c,d,e,f$. I'm supposed to find relative uncertainty in $a$.

As far as I have learnt, we have $$\%\frac{\Delta a}{a}=\%\frac{\Delta b}{b}+\%\frac{\Delta c}{c}+\%\frac{\Delta d}{d}+\%\frac{\Delta e}{e}+\%\frac{\Delta f}{f}$$
The $\%$ sign indicates that the relative uncertainties are in percentage.

However, is this actually correct, that is, are relative uncertainties really additive? I couldn't find a good reference which explicitly states so.

Comment: In the model usually used in things like elementary physics, yes. It should be stated in physics books. This model has some assumptions which are not always reasonable.

Comment: Well, the original question does have quantities which are physical. I just want to know whether we find the relative uncertainty in that above stated way..

Comment: The answer is probably yes, unless this is a fairly advanced class.

Comment: Oh, sorry, this is actually not what I've usually seen written down. Usually I see that under multiplication/division, relative uncertainties add in the same way that absolute uncertainties add, i.e. if $a$ has relative uncertainty $p$ and $b$ has relative uncertainty $q$ then $ab$ has relative uncertainty $\sqrt{p^2+q^2}$.

Comment: @Ian, your formula is based on the uncertainty being defined as the standard deviation. The formula used by the OP is simpler and is based on the uncertainty being defined in terms of derivatives. For instance if $m=ab$ then $\mathrm{d}m/m = \mathrm{d}a/a + \mathrm{d}b/b$. This second formula is sometimes taught in lab classes, thought the use of the standard deviation is more "standard".

Answer (score 0):

I think that's perhaps not the best way to handle the errors. For instance, if $e$ is small but has a large error this will greatly influence the error. Perhaps consider the linear approximation $L$ to the function? That's assuming that you can ignore second order errors.

We have:
\begin{align*}
a(b,c,d,e,f)&\approx L(b,c,d,e,f)\\
&=a(b_0,c_0,d_0,e_0,f_0)+\frac{\partial a}{\partial b}(b-b_0)+\frac{\partial a}{\partial c}(c-c_0)+\\
&+\frac{\partial a}{\partial d}(d-d_0)+\frac{\partial a}{\partial e}(b-b_0). 
\end{align*}

Therefore $$\left|\frac{\partial a}{\partial b}(b-b_0)+\frac{\partial a}{\partial c}(c-c_0)+\\
+\frac{\partial a}{\partial d}(d-d_0)+\frac{\partial a}{\partial e}(b-b_0)\right|$$ will give an approximation to the absolute uncertainty in $a$. Probably you'd estimate this using the triangle inequality.